# How to monitor the network traffic of a Python-based package by incorporating WireShark?

Tags: python-3.x, wireshark, network-monitoring

I am trying to find ways to monitor the network traffic of a Python-based package. One suggested approach is by incorporating WireShark to the package. I have never done anything like this before, and could not find any tutorials on the Internet regarding this. And, whatever I could gather, it seems to be suggested using PyShark as wrapper to perform the task. Could someone please offer me some guidance such as code snippets or pointers on how I could tackle the task? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out I can probably use `TShark` or `pyshark` for my purposes to monitor the network traffic of a Python-based package. For details please see official documentation at https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html. Can follow the sources below for what I originally wanted to do:

- https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/using-tshark-watch-and-inspect-network-traffic
- https://github.com/KimiNewt/pyshark

---

Update as of July 17, 2019:

So the main thing to note for me was to note that there are two methods in pyshark I could use to capture packets, namely `FileCapture` or `LiveCapture`. `FileCapture` is mostly for reading from a capture file, so it was not that useful for me, as I wanted to capture some live event. On the other hand, `LiveCapture` is for reading from a live interface, so I opted to use it for monitoring live network traffic. So I wrote the following code snippet to capture some tcp packets transmitted on my laptop:

```
@staticmethod
def get_packet_info(interface=None):
    """
    Returns the size of the transmitted data using Wireshark.

    Args:
        interface: A string. Name of the interface to sniff on.

    Returns: Size of the packet sent over WebSockets in a given event.
    """
    if interface is None:
        raise Exception("Please provide the interface used.")
    else:
        capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface=interface)
        capture.sniff(timeout=60)
        for packet in capture:
            try:
                packet_info = packet.pretty_print()
            except:
                raise Exception("Cannot determine packet info.")
        return packet_info
```

The argument of `sniff` can be changed from `timeout` to something like `packet_count`. Additionally, I could add more attributes to LiveCapture for better control.